# Airflow worker custom DAGBag loader

Tags: airflow

I am having a custom DAGBag loader as described [here](https://medium.com/@xnuinside/how-to-load-use-several-dag-folders-airflow-dagbags-b93e4ef4663c) to load dags from different folders. Depending on the folder, I am setting an environment variable:

```
""" add additional DAGs folders """
import os
from airflow.models import DagBag


for stage in stages:
   os.environ['ENVIRONMENT'] = stage
   dir = f'/usr/local/airflow/dags/{stage}'
   dag_bag = DagBag(os.path.expanduser(dir))

   if dag_bag:
      for dag_id, dag in dag_bag.dags.items():
         globals()[dag_id] = dag
```

In the dag file itself I get the environment variable and set the task id correspondingly:

```
...
stage = os.environ.get('ENVIRONMENT')

with DAG(f'{stage}',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval=None) as dag:
...
```

This works perfectly for the webserver and I can see everything in the UI. However, the worker does not seem to load the Dags using my custom file and thus does not set the environment variable. The task id is none and thus the worker is not executing the dag and fails.

```
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: staging. Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse.
```

All files are present in the filesystem of the worker. Why is the webserver using my DAGBag loader but the worker is not? Any workaround?